# The output of cout << 1 && 0;

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I don't understand why the below code prints `1`.

`1 && 0` is not the same as `true && false` -> `false`?

Why doesn't this print `0`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << 1 && 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: did you try `cout << true && false;` :P

Comment: That's another reason why overloading bit-shift operators for I/O was bad idea.

Comment: Expand your experiment with for instance `cout << 2 && 3;`, `cout << 1 && 0 << 3;`, `cout << 1 && 0 << "hello";`.

Comment: You are correct.  The result is 0.  The code is doing this: `(cout << 1) && 0;` and that does yield 0.

Comment: Follow-up question: WTH is calling `operator && (std::ostream&, int)` not a type error?

Comment: @leftaroundabout streams are implicitly convertible to `bool` so you can do things like `while (cin >> number) { ... }`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's all about [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

The Overloaded Bitwise Left Shift Operator `operator<<(std::basic_ostream)` has a higher priority than the Logical AND Operator `&&`.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << (1 && 0);
    return 0;
}
```

If you are not 146% sure about the priority of an operator, do not hesitate to use brackets. Most modern IDEs will tell you if you don't need to use them.

Comment: `<<` in this case is **not** the left shift operator. It is the [ostream operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2).

Comment: @Drise, should I edit it to Overloaded Bitwise Left Shift Operator `<<` `(operator<<(std::basic_ostream)`? I doubt how it will be right in English.

Comment: Yes, that is more pedantically correct.

Comment: Precedence is part of the grammar, so it doesn't matter which type's implementation will ultimately be used. It would suffice to say "`<<` has a higher precedence than `&&`".

Comment: ... until the next version of the language, where you can overload the precedence itself.