# operator<< with cout and precedence

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, operator-precedence, comparison-operators

The accepted answers to the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49195740/the-output-of-cout-1-0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952726/logical-operations-in-cout) say that it's all about operator precedence and thus,

```
cout << i && j ;
```

is evaluated as

```
(cout << i) &&j ;
```

since the precedence of Bitwise-Operators is greater than that of Logical-Operators. (It's not the bitwise operator here, but it is the symbol itself which is setting the precedence.)

I wonder then why the following code doesn't output 1:

```
int x=2, y=1 ;
cout << x>y ;
```

since the precedence of Relational-Operators is greater than Bitwise-Operators; the last line should get treated as `cout << (x>y) ;`.

I got a warning that overloaded `operator<<` has higher precedence than a comparison operator.

What is the precedence of overloaded `operator<<` in comparison to all other existing operators?

Comment: The relational operators `<` and `>` still have lower [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the "shift" operators `<<` and `>>`.

Comment: You said that *"is evaluated as,..."* which is wrong. It should instead be **grouped as**.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, my bad, i thought precedence of BW Shift to similar to BW AND/OR/XOR. Yes BW 'shift' has greater precedence then Relationals op.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> someone tell what is the precedence of overloaded operator << in comparison to all other existing operators?

The *inserter* `<<` has higher precedence than the relational `operator<`, `operator>` etc. Refer to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

This means that `cout << x>y` is **grouped as**(and not evaluated as):

```
(cout << x)>y;
```

Now, `cout << x` returns a reference to `cout` which is then used as the left hand operand of `operator>`. But since there is no overloaded `operator>` that takes `cout` as left hand operand and `int` as right hand operand you get the error saying exactly that:

```
 error: no match for ‘operator>’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream’ and ‘int’)
```

---

##### Note

Additionally, in your question you've used the phrase *"is evaluated as"* which is incorrect. The correct phrase would be *"is grouped as"*.

Comment: can u further clarify why we were not getting error in the case of (cout<<i)&&j. Do such overloaded Logical operators exist (to take cout as left hand operand) ?

Comment: @new_to_cpp Because operands are converted to `bool`. The same is explained here: [Logical operations in cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952726/logical-operations-in-cout)

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the precedence of the bitwise shift operator is greater than the precedence of relational operators. `cout <<`, despite being a I/O operation, is an overload of the bitwise shift operators.