# Why is my Boolean operation in VS Code not given expected result?

Tags: c++, boolean, boolean-operations

I tried to solve C++ expression quizzes on TLX. There is a problem about Boolean operation which I got confused. The question is like "If a = true, b = false, c = true, and d = true, then the value of a && !d || !c || a && b is ..." and the answer is false.

I had tried to write a code in VS Code to see the output, I got 1 as the result instead of 0. Indeed, the answer should be false when we follow the operator precedence. But why in VS Code it seems like the execution didn't work as it should?

Here is the code I wrote in VS Code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool a, b, c, d;
    a = true;
    b = false;
    c = true;
    d = true;
    
    cout << a && !d || !c || a && b;
}
```

Comment: You're printing only `a`, `<<` has higher precedence than `&&`.

Comment: Try `cout << (a && !d || !c || a && b);` to get `false`.

Comment: Read about [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) Also [operator<< with cout and precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73670908/operator-with-cout-and-precedence)

Comment: What is TLX? Even if there are clear rules on operator precedence, take the time to add `(` and `)` to make your expression more readable/understandable. Eg. `((a&&!d) || (!c) || (a&&b))`

Comment: C++ compilers are designed to never warn about pointless code like  cout && !d; those instead optimise it silently out.

Comment: @PepijnKramer TLX is a website to learn a programming language (C++) in my country. It can be used for Informatics National Olympiad preparation.